# Get the value of specific XML emements and add them to an array in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Using the XML below as an example, I'm trying to get the content of all `<d:LayerXml>` tags and add them to an array.  To parse the XML I'm using ElementTree.

I first treid to access the XML elements using there names, but this failed as apparently there are no elements named 'entry' -

```
root = ET.fromstring(r.text)
for child in root:
    if child.tag == entry':
        print child.attirb
```

After I printed out all of the child tags (`print child.tag`), I noticed that each was suffixed with the xmlns supplied in the roor element.  For example, 'entry' was actually '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}'.

So next I tried to access elements using that suffix, but it just failed with a syntax error.

```
root = ET.fromstring(r.text)
for child in root:
    if child.tag == '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry':
        layerXML = child.{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}content
# Also tried - layerXML = child.'{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}content'
        print layerXML
```

So given the following XML sample, how could I add the content of all `<d:LayerXml>` elements to an array.  To clarify, in this case the array would contain `I want this` and `I want this, too`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="https://tablestore.somewhere.com/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <id>https://tablestore.somewhere.com/TableName</id>
    <title type="text">TableName</title>
    <updated>2017-03-02T12:01:04Z</updated>
    <link rel="self" title="TableName" href="TableName" />
    <entry m:etag="W/&quot;datetime'2017-03-02T11%3A46%3A37.1271167Z'&quot;">
        <id>https://tablestore.somewhere.com/TableName(PartitionKey='PartitonKey',RowKey='layer1-tileMatrixSet')</id>
        <category term="tablestore.TableName" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <link rel="edit" title="TableName" href="TableName(PartitionKey='PartitonKey',RowKey='layer1-tileMatrixSet')" />
        <title />
        <updated>2017-03-02T12:01:04Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:PartitionKey>PartitonKey</d:PartitionKey>
                <d:RowKey>RowKey</d:RowKey>
                <d:Timestamp m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-03-02T11:46:37.1271167Z</d:Timestamp>
                <d:AuthType>basic</d:AuthType>
                <d:Credentials>CREDENTIALS1</d:Credentials>
                <d:Layer>layer1</d:Layer>
                <d:LayerXml>I want this</d:LayerXml>
                <d:Service>https://www.google.co.uk</d:Service>
                <d:TileMatrixSet>tileMatrixSet</d:TileMatrixSet>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry m:etag="W/&quot;datetime'2017-03-02T11%3A46%3A37.1271167Z'&quot;">
        <id>https://tablestore.somewhere.com/TableName(PartitionKey='PartitonKey',RowKey='layer2-tileMatrixSet')</id>
        <category term="tablestore.TableName" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <link rel="edit" title="TableName" href="TableName(PartitionKey='PartitonKey',RowKey='layer2-tileMatrixSet')" />
        <title />
        <updated>2017-03-02T12:01:04Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:PartitionKey>PartitonKey</d:PartitionKey>
                <d:RowKey>RowKey</d:RowKey>
                <d:Timestamp m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-03-02T11:46:37.1271167Z</d:Timestamp>
                <d:AuthType>basic</d:AuthType>
                <d:Credentials>CREDENTIALS1</d:Credentials>
                <d:Layer>layer2</d:Layer>
                <d:LayerXml>I want this, too</d:LayerXml>
                <d:Service>https://www.google.co.uk</d:Service>
                <d:TileMatrixSet>tileMatrixSet</d:TileMatrixSet>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said which syntax error you got, the following gives the wanted result for me:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="https://tablestore.somewhere.com/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <id>https://tablestore.somewhere.com/TableName</id>
    <title type="text">TableName</title>
    <updated>2017-03-02T12:01:04Z</updated>
    <link rel="self" title="TableName" href="TableName" />
    <entry m:etag="W/&quot;datetime'2017-03-02T11%3A46%3A37.1271167Z'&quot;">
        <id>https://tablestore.somewhere.com/TableName(PartitionKey='PartitonKey',RowKey='layer1-tileMatrixSet')</id>
        <category term="tablestore.TableName" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <link rel="edit" title="TableName" href="TableName(PartitionKey='PartitonKey',RowKey='layer1-tileMatrixSet')" />
        <title />
        <updated>2017-03-02T12:01:04Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:PartitionKey>PartitonKey</d:PartitionKey>
                <d:RowKey>RowKey</d:RowKey>
                <d:Timestamp m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-03-02T11:46:37.1271167Z</d:Timestamp>
                <d:AuthType>basic</d:AuthType>
                <d:Credentials>CREDENTIALS1</d:Credentials>
                <d:Layer>layer1</d:Layer>
                <d:LayerXml>I want this</d:LayerXml>
                <d:Service>https://www.google.co.uk</d:Service>
                <d:TileMatrixSet>tileMatrixSet</d:TileMatrixSet>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
    <entry m:etag="W/&quot;datetime'2017-03-02T11%3A46%3A37.1271167Z'&quot;">
        <id>https://tablestore.somewhere.com/TableName(PartitionKey='PartitonKey',RowKey='layer2-tileMatrixSet')</id>
        <category term="tablestore.TableName" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <link rel="edit" title="TableName" href="TableName(PartitionKey='PartitonKey',RowKey='layer2-tileMatrixSet')" />
        <title />
        <updated>2017-03-02T12:01:04Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name />
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:PartitionKey>PartitonKey</d:PartitionKey>
                <d:RowKey>RowKey</d:RowKey>
                <d:Timestamp m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-03-02T11:46:37.1271167Z</d:Timestamp>
                <d:AuthType>basic</d:AuthType>
                <d:Credentials>CREDENTIALS1</d:Credentials>
                <d:Layer>layer2</d:Layer>
                <d:LayerXml>I want this, too</d:LayerXml>
                <d:Service>https://www.google.co.uk</d:Service>
                <d:TileMatrixSet>tileMatrixSet</d:TileMatrixSet>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
'''
feed = ET.fromstring(xml)
values = [value.text for value in feed.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry/{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}content/{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata}properties/{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices}LayerXml')]
print(values)
```

Actually, it seems you can also use

```
values = [value.text for value in feed.findall('.//{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices}LayerXml')]
```

or

```
values = [value.text for value in feed.findall('.//d:LayerXml', { 'd' : 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' })]
```

if you don't want to list the full path.

Comment: Thank you, that appears to be doing the job.  And FYI, the sytax error I saw literally said "SyntaxError: invalid syntax", and pointed to the curly brackets. Thanks again.